# How can you change the date format in New Relic?

Tags: newrelic

New Relic defaults to displaying the date in US format (mm/dd, e.g. 11/27 00:42). How can you change this to dd/mm (i.e. 27/11 00:42)? It doesn't pick up the correct format from the "Time zone" setting under "User preferences", e.g. "(GMT+10:00) Melbourne".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now it's not possible to change the date format from the backward US style. I will let our Product managers know that you're among those who would like to see this feature. I wish I had better news for you. To add a bit of weight to the request, I'd ask you to open a ticket at support.newrelic.com requesting this feature.

Comment: Ticket opened. Thanks!

Comment: As I implied, you're not the only person to request, but every person who gets in touch is one more vote, thanks!